# ImageView full screen but too large

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I'm trying to display an ImageView like this

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tuto_continue"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tuto_title"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/tuto1" />
```

It should normally fill the whole width. The real size of the picture is 1000*1089 but at runtime I get a `Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2000x2178, max=2048x2048)`

How could I display my image in the whole space available on all devices? I don't want it to be upscaled in xxhdpi nor xxxhdpi in order to prevent pixelation.

Thanks

Comment: Check out Google's Article on [Loading Large Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll read it!

Comment: Ok that pretty well working. Just one thing.
I'm doing img.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), image, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
but as expected getWidth and getHeight return 0, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This happens:

1. Your bitmap is in res/drawable
2. You run the app on xhdpi device (your bitmap is scaled to 2x size)

You can:

1. Move the bitmap into res/drawable-xhdpi
2. Or set android:layerType="software"